# Get segment from url CodeIgniter but not first

Tags: codeigniter, url, codeigniter-3

I know i can get all segments from url like this

Lets say i have this example link

**www.example.com/de/products.html**

Using url_helper like this:

```
$data['url'] = $this->uri->uri_string();
```

I will get value like this

**de/products**

But i dont need first segment **de**, only **products**, the problem is that
i dont know how many segments it will be, i only need to remove the first

Is there possible to forget first segment with url helper in CI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this...

Use the php's `explode()` function to make the url string as array.Then apply array's `array_shift()` function which always removes the first element from array.

Code is looks like as below

```
        $data= $this->uri->uri_string();
        $arr=explode('/', $data);
        array_shift($arr);
        //print_r($arr);
```

Then use the php's `implode()` method to get the `URI` without first segment.Hope it will works...

```
$uri=implode('/',$arr);
echo $uri;
```

Comment: @Miomir Dancevic thanks.....may be simple but tricky....lets enjoy with codeigniter.

Comment: @HikmatSijapati Already inbuilt with `$this->uri->segment_array();`. [Docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html#CI_URI::segment_array).

Answer (score 1):

example:

```
<?php  
      $data=$this->uri->segment(2);
      $val=explode('.', $data);
      echo $val[0]; 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no URL helper in the CI to forget the first segment. However you can easily make a custom one and put @Hikmat's answer below it in the application/helpers/MY_url_helper.php in the Core folder.

e.g.

```
function my_forget_first_segment() {
    $data= $this->uri->uri_string();
        $arr=explode('/', $data);
        array_shift($arr);
        $uri=implode('/',$arr);
        return $uri;
}
```

Before Edit answer.

```
You need to try this 

$second_segment = $this->uri->segment(2);
```

From Codeigniter documentation -

```
$this->uri->segment(n);
```

Permits you to retrieve a specific segment. Where n is the segment number you wish to retrieve. Segments are numbered from left to right. For example, if your full URL is this:

http://example.com/index.php/news/local/metro/crime_is_up

The segment numbers would be this:

```
1. news
2. local
3. metro
4. crime_is_up
```

The optional second parameter defaults to NULL and allows you to set the return value of this method when the requested URI segment is missing. For example, this would tell the method to return the number zero in the event of failure:

```
$product_id = $this->uri->segment(3, 0);
```

Comment: @Miomir Dancevic i think your problem is sloved on my answer.See first if not comment